# Strict aliasing rule and copy kernel in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, language-lawyer

### Background

I want to copy many arrays (they may have different types), like

```cpp
cudaMemcpy(dst0, src0, num0 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dst1, src1, num1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dst2, src2, num2 * sizeof(int16_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

Since each array is not so big, a single copy kernel is faster than calling `cudaMemcpy` N times. The kernel looks like

```cpp
__global__ void copy_kernel(void **dst, void **src, int num_arrays, const int* array_sizes, const int* type_sizes) {...}

int main() {
    ... // prepare data etc.
    copy_kernel<<<num_arrays, 1024>>>(dst, src, num_arrays, array_sizes, type_sizes);
    ...
}
```

For simplicity, we only consider one array and call like `copy_kernel<<<1, 1024>>>(...)` in the following examples. Let's assume the array is of type `float` and `sizeof(float)=sizeof(int32_t)=4`.

### Implementations

The first implementation is simple and fast, but is not so useful because other arrays are not float arrays.

```
__global__ void copy_kernel_float(float* dst, const float* src, int num) {
    for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < num; i += blockDim.x) {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
}
```

The second implementation can support any types, but is not so fast, I think the reason is that 32-byte transaction is slower than 128-byte transaction.

```
__global__ void copy_kernel_any(void* dst, const void* src, int num,
                                int type_size) {
    int num_char = num * type_size;
    auto my_dst = reinterpret_cast<char*>(dst);
    auto my_src = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(src);
    for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < num_char; i += blockDim.x) {
        my_dst[i] = my_src[i];
    }
}
```

The third implementation can also support any types, and is as fast as the first one, but I'm afraid that it violates strict aliasing rule. For simplicity, we assume `num * type_size % sizeof(int32_t) = 0` here.

```
__global__ void copy_kernel_any_packed(void* dst, const void* src, int num,
                                       int type_size) {
    int num_int32 = num * type_size / sizeof(int32_t);
    auto my_dst = reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(dst);
    auto my_src = reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(src);
    for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < num_int32; i += blockDim.x) {
        my_dst[i] = my_src[i];
    }
}
```

### Questions

1. Is the third implementation valid or not? As I know, reinterpret_cast `float*` to `int32_t*` is undefined behavior in c++, and I think that `reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dst))` doesn't help.
2. Am I right about the performance of memory transaction? I also write two valid kernels that copy 10,000,000 float values, and copy by float is as fast as `cudaMemcpy` (~0.4ms), while copy by char is slower (~0.6ms) on my 1070Ti.
3. If the third implementation violates strict aliasing rule, is there any implementation that is both valid and fast? (something like copy 4 chars in one instruction)

Correct me if any of my statements are wrong. :)

Comment: cuda doesn't have a standard, I don't know what you're looking for with language-lawyering.

Comment: I didn't know `cuda doesn't have a standard` before. I think that tag can help me find someone who is very familiar with rules of cuda language.

Comment: They do document standard compliance https://gist.github.com/ax3l/9489132#device-side-c-standard-support

Comment: maybe you can use `cub::DeviceMemcpy::Batched`

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the strict aliasing rule applies here. There is no `float *` in the kernel/device code that gets aliased, so there is no strict aliasing assumption of the compiler that you can break by working with the `înt32_t *`. Either way the solution for legal type punning is `memcpy`. It should be available in device code, but I'm not sure what size of transaction will be used when every thread does a 4 byte `memcpy` from/to global memory. You could try it out. Otherwise there is also `char4`, for which I don't know how if it will act like `char` in terms of aliasing.

Comment: Forget about `memcpy`, it will generate four single byte loads  instead of a single four byte load even if the size and alignment are known to the compiler. It is still the right tool for doing actual type punning in a kernel, i.e. to `memcpy` from one local variable to another and hope that the compiler will do the right thing and ignore the `memcpy`/reuse the register. But that doesn't help you here.

Comment: `cub::DeviceMemcpy::Batched` looks like a solution, but sadly I can't get it compiled. https://godbolt.org/z/eT8qTTEG8  , uncomment the cub part and I get `ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '__cudaCDP2GetParameterBuffer'`

Comment: You need `-rdc=true -lcudadevrt` as described in the [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (CDP) documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compiling-and-linking).

Comment: `cub::DeviceMemcpy::Batched` works now. `char4` is better for my requirement, but I'm still not sure if `float* -> char* -> char4*` violates strict aliasing rule. I guess it's OK to use in practice as something like a compiler extension. As for C++, intel intrinsics also have apis like `_mm256_load_si256` which casts `int32_t* -> __m256i*`

Comment: Like I alluded to before, if you know why aliasing is seen as undefined behavior (to enable certain compiler optimizations), I see no reason to worry about the given code. If you were accessing the same memory through differently typed pointers **in the same kernel**, that would be more critical, although I was not able to generate a problematic kernel on Compiler Explorer. Undefined behavior can be acceptable if it is still deterministic for a particular vendor. And CUDA code isn't portable to other vendors either way... Although I would love to have a rules for this from Nvidia as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are simpler and more effective ways: using templates!

```
 template<typename T>
 __global__ void myMemcpy(const int nbr,T*src,T*dst)
 {
      const int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;          
      if(id<nbr)
          dst[id] = src[id];

 }
```

1 kernel to copy any kind of data for any size!

Comment: I'm afraid templates can't help here. Maybe I didn't make it clear. The kernel is to copy several arrays of different types by just one kernel execution, not copy one array at a time.

Comment: What I do in this case is launch one kernel per data item and make a single call to cudaDeviceSynchronize(); As your arrays appear to be small, all copies of all types will be made in parallel.

Comment: I think that in that case, you'll have to use different streams for different arrays, otherwise they will be forced to run serially on the default stream. Also, I think the bottleneck is kernel execution cost in the case, and many kernel calls is as bad as many `cudaMemcpy`, otherwise why don't I call `cudaMemcpy` directly?

Comment: In my case, a molecular dynamics stuff, i just need to copy datas once time. That's not the bottleneck in my case.